# How would you find the number of items within an array of records for a specific class

Tags: python

The following code:

```py
class examp():
   def __init__(self):
       self.height = 0

print(len(example.height))
```

produces this error:

```py
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'height'
```

Comment: Are you sure thats the code you were running when you received this error message? There's no mention of `age` and no uses of `list`'s in the code you've posted

Comment: Please provide a full example. The code you provided would not work since `example` is never defined. Also it never uses `age`.

Comment: have you tried creating an object from your "examp" class? `e = examp()` then you should be able to call `e.height`; len() won't work as height is an integer and not a list
it would really help if you provide a more detailed code example here

Answer (score 0):

The error is not supported by the code. `age` variable doesn't even appear in the given code example. Assuming you want to retrieve `height` from the examp class, you first need to instantiate the class like this:

```
ex = examp()
```

and then print the height to the screen:

```
print(ex.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Examp:
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height
```

This is the correct syntax for what you have.

However your error is most likely coming form running the wrong file.
You are probably using and IDE and have multiple .py files open.
Click run and select this file

This will still return an error because self.height wont have a length as it will be a literal

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems like when I do

print(len(example))

it does give the value I was required.

Sorry for the inconveniences caused.